# 01722. 00000 - "invalid number" : Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a `table1` with

```
t1id       NUMBER(10,0)
channel_id NUMBER(10,0)
```

and another `table2` with columns

```
t1id        NUMBER(10,0)
channel2_id NVARCHAR2(100 CHAR)
cl2_id      NVARCHAR2(100 CHAR)
```

Having called the query

```
SELECT t1.id, t2.cl2_id
  FROM table1  t1 
  LEFT JOIN table2 t2 
    ON t1.channel_id  = c.channel2_id;
```

I recieve the below error while joining the query.? Is it due to the data type of both the columns? how to resolve this

> ```
> 01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
> *Cause:    The specified number was invalid.
> *Action:   Specify a valid number.
> ```

Comment: What is that `c` in your query? I assume that's supposed to be `t2.channel2_id`? If that's the case, then `t1.channel_id` is a NUMBER but `t2.channel2_id` is an NVARCHAR. There is some automatic type conversion. But at least one value in `t2.channel2_id` can't be converted to a number

Comment: Yes, that should be the reason. Using `TO_CHAR(t1.channel_id)  = c.channel2_id` might be a workaround, but prefer storing `channel2_id` as number as well if that contains whole numeric values without left-leaded zeroes provided that's possible for your DB.

Comment: You join char to number, of course this is the reason. You may find erroneous records with `select * from table2 where validate_conversion(channel2_id as number(10, 0)) = 0`

Answer (score 0):

If you have a datatype mismatch, we will (silently) try to correct that mismatch, eg

```
SQL> create table t ( num_col_stored_as_string  varchar2(10));

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> insert into t values ('123');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into t values ('456');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into t values ('789');

1 row created.

SQL>
SQL> explain plan for
  2  select * from t
  3  where num_col_stored_as_string = 456;

Explained.

SQL>
SQL> select * from dbms_xplan.display();

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 1601196873

--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |      |     1 |     7 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| T    |     1 |     7 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter(TO_NUMBER("NUM_COL_STORED_AS_STRING")=456)
```

Notice that we silently added a TO_NUMBER to the filter to ensure that the column matched with the input value (456).

It then becomes obvious as to why this can cause problems, because:

```
SQL> insert into t values ('NOT A NUM');

1 row created.

SQL> select * from t
  2  where num_col_stored_as_string = 456;
ERROR:
ORA-01722: invalid number
```

As others have suggested in comments, look at

- getting your datatypes aligned
- use TO_CHAR
- use VALIDATE_CONVERSION

but ideally, data type alignment is the way to go